# Is this a SQL Azure bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

<strike>[If this isn't an issue specific to Stack Exchange Data Explorer, this question is on the wrong site.]</strike>

```
Select VoteTypeId, Count(*), DatePart(hour,CreationDate)
From Votes
Group By VoteTypeId, DatePart(hour,CreationDate)
```

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1693

returns count(*)=0 for all VoteTypeIds.

This is fixed by adding an as clause for the Count(*)!

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1695

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in data explorer which I will sort out pretty soon, if there is more than one column with the same name (or no name) the data rendered into the grid goes wacky.

So this works:

```
Select VoteTypeId, Count(*) as a, DatePart(hour,CreationDate) as b 
From Votes
Group By VoteTypeId, DatePart(hour,CreationDate)
```

Comment: OK, so a simpler example is `SELECT @@VERSION, COUNT(*)`.

Comment: BTW The original query was confirming all Votes are dated, but without times. Is this just the data that was transferred or does SO really not record the time votes are awarded?

Comment: @Mark, they are scrubbed in the dump, as are the vote owners